# Nginx cache not built with curl request

Tags: php, caching, curl, nginx

I'm trying to build the nginx cache for a certain URL by making a curl request to it, but the cache never gets built.

```
public function crawlUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Are there certain headers I need to set to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question using nginx fastcgi cache, did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your caching is enabled when you make the request (cookies, url excluded from cache...).

In my case I was parsing a xml sitemap from production and checking the cache on my dev environement... Double check your target address, with the right url it should work out of the box:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

It shouldn't be needed, but you could try with a fresh connection and new cookies:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```